# Is there any relationship between Paillier Cryptosystem's random r and other factors

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I want to try run an example of  Paillier cryptosystem(Algorithm), So i just started with some basic examples, but cannot obtain correct result/decryption. 
I just change random factor `r` from 97 to 101 in [Reliable Implementation of Paillier Cryptosystem](https://www.iasj.net/iasj?func=fulltext&aId=97260), and return with wrong result. is there any relation between the random `r` and other Paillier factors i,e; `g, λ, n` etc
The other example is:

**Key Gen:**

```
p = 5, q = 7 ,n =3 5 ,n² = 1225;
g = n+1 = 36;
λ = LCM(p-1,q-1) = 12;
μ = L(g^λ mod n²)^(-1) mod n 
μ = L(36^12 mod 1225)^(-1) mod 35 
μ = L(421)^(-1) mod 35
μ = 3    ; where L(421) = 12
```

**Encryption:**

```
Let m = 32; random r = 17;
c = ((g^m) * (r^n)) (mod n^2) 
c = ((36^32) * (17^35)) mod 1225 
c = 278
```

**Decryption:**

```
m = L(C^λ mod n^2) * μ (mod n);
m = L((278^12) mod 1225) *3; 
m = 1191*3 mod 35;
m = 3;
```

But the original message is 32. what is wrong?
I went through some other example, but unable to decrypt correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in decryption.

You wrote:

```
m = 1191*3 mod 35
```

You lost `L(...)` here. Instead of `1191` it should be `L(1191)`:

```
m = L(1191)*3 mod 35
L(1191) = 34
m = 34*3 mod 35
m = 102 mod 35
m = 32
```

Voilà. We got the original message.